# Dict append - multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to build up a data frame as a dict first before using df.from_dict to convert all the data into a dataframe more efficiently.

I've set up an empty dict with the right structure using:

```
d =df.head(0).to_dict()
```

It appears I can then add to the 'first row' by doing things like this:
d['UserID']=1
d['EstProb']=1
etc.

Which gives me the dict output:

```
{'EstProb': 1, 'PlayCount': 1, 'PlayDate': 1, 'Timeslot': 1, 'UserID': 1}
```

But how do I go beyond this one row and continue to add more rows into the dict?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I solved this:

I first created an empty nested dict structure like so:

```
d={}
d['UserID']={}
d['PlayDate']={}
d['Timeslot']={}
```

And I initialized `i =0` too

I then went through a loop and built up my nested dict like so:

```
for x in range (0, 100):
    d['UserID'][i] = u[x]
    d['PlayDate'][i] = p[x]
    d['Timeslot'][i] = t[x]
    i+=1
```

Finally I turned the dict into a data frame like so:

```
df=df.from_dict(d)
```

The new solution works a lot faster (6 seconds vs 30 min) than my previous method using dataframe.append